No internet connection (both ethernet & wifi) after 24.04 upgrade
I have just updated Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on my laptop, and I seem to have internet problems. After both (ethernet & wifi) working in the previous version, I have no internet connection through wifi or Ethernet.
once PC opens it shows connected on ethernet/wifi but no internet
internet only works once I run this command
dhcpcd

